# What causes this SoftLayer_Exception_Public error message?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am seeing the following error message returned from Softlayer when trying to create a new device:

> SoftLayer_Exception_Public: Could not obtain network VLAN with id
>   1865415. (HTTP 500)

I have successfully created 2 other devices with the same VLAN id but cannot create another one. What does this message mean and what could be causing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

> The message means that the vlan doesn't exist in your account.

Probably you are using another credentials or the vlan doesn't exist into your account, please make double check the credentials and the vlan exists into your account.

I understand that you had success with two servers before, but if your are using the same credentials, it's necessary more information like the credentials and the script/code that you tried, in order to dig more into this.

You can submit a ticket for further assistance or provide the script that you tried

Comment: Thanks Ruber. I was referred to here from my original ticket, 42401137. I added some details to the ticket, but in short I'm dubious about the credentials theory as the next day using the same shell session that was already authenticated I was able to successfully run the commands. About script/code, I'm using IBM's Armada interface which is then calling on to SoftLayer, using a command such as the following to add a new worker node to the cluster:
```
bx cs worker-add --cluster ys1 --workers 1 --public-vlan 1865413 --private-vlan 1865415 --machine-type b1c.4x16
```

Comment: Dan, I reviewed the ticket and I verified that it's possible to order VMs in **1865415** vlan through API

Comment: My apologies, but I'm not able to access to bluemix, I hope someone from that side can help you